# Java libraries in machine learning

Tags: java, machine-learning

I'm doing a big machine learning project in Java.

I tried some libraries but they were uncomfortable. Not many algorithms, few examples, unclear function parameters.

So, I wanted to ask if anyone knew a convenient library in Java for machine learning. (In terms of: easy to import, easy to use, lots of samples, etc.)

In addition, I have already read the csv file to a matrix. So if the library uses it, it will be better. Thank you.

Comment: Asking for off site resources is fully off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are a few links**

ApacheSAMOA: https://samoa.incubator.apache.org/

Weka: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

Rapid Miner: https://rapidminer.com/